# How to get File Path or URI after Saving it through Android native(PRINT) Dialog?

Tags: android, pdf, file-manager

The Print api is added in android in KITKAT. I used it to save PDF of content loaded in webView.

An native Dialog open and give option of print or save as PDF.

if user select save as PDF option . open an file explore and saves the file.

**I want PATH SAVED FILE .**

I am using following method to print PDF

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView
            .createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";

    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}
```

[Android developer docs on printing](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html)

Comment: do you have any progress ?

Comment: Is there any solution for this question?

Comment: No dude!...........